# Android Java LocationManager not removing LocationListener

Tags: java, android, location, locationlistener

I am working on a simple GeoFence Service. I am not using the GeofencingApi because I am working with a jni bridge and making the library available would be to much overhead for my project.

So my Problem now is, that the LocationManager is not removing Updates after I am calling removeUpdates. I don't understand why. My code is as follows:

```
public class GeoFenceService extends Service {
    public GeoFenceService() { Log.v("GeoFenceService","GeoFenceService init"); }

    public static LocationManager mlocManager;
    public static LocationListener mlocListener;

    public void updateLocationAndCheckGeoFences() {
        Log.d("GeoFenceService","Updating Location");
        GeoFenceService.mlocManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        GeoFenceService.mlocListener = new MyLocationListener();
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
        String bestProvider = GeoFenceService.mlocManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
        GeoFenceService.mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(bestProvider, 0, 0, GeoFenceService.mlocListener);
        //Location loc = mlocManager.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);
        //checkGeoFences4(loc);
    }

    public void checkGeoFences4(Location locCurrent) {
        Log.d("GeoFenceService","Checking GeoFence for Location:"
              +locCurrent.getLatitude()+"/"+locCurrent.getLongitude());
        for (Voucher voucher : listVouchers) {
            Location locVoucher = new Location("Voucher");
            locVoucher.setLatitude(voucher.dblLat);
            locVoucher.setLongitude(voucher.dblLon);
            float distance = locCurrent.distanceTo(locVoucher);
            Log.d("GeoFenceService","\tGeoFence for Voucher"+voucher.strText+" Distance:"+distance);
            if (distance < voucher.dblRadius) {
                showNotification(voucher.strText,voucher.intEntryId);
            }
        }
    }

    public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener
    {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location loc)
        {
            try {
                checkGeoFences4(loc);
                try {
                    GeoFenceService.mlocManager.removeUpdates(GeoFenceService.mlocListener);
                    Log.d("GeoFenceService","Location Update suspended");
                } catch(Exception e) {
                    Log.e("GeoFenceService","Failed to suspend Location Update"+e.getMessage());
                }
            } catch (Exception e) { }
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider)
        {
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider)
        {
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras)
        {
        }
    }
    
    //Stuff for class GeoFenceService (simplyfied)
    
    private final int UPDATE_INTERVAL = 15 * 60 * 1000;
    private Timer timer = new Timer();

    public void onCreate() { Log.d("GeoFenceService","GeoFenceService created"); }
    public void onDestroy() { if (timer != null) { timer.cancel(); } }
    
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startid) {
        Log.d("GeoFenceService","GeoFenceService started");
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                updateLocationAndCheckGeoFences();
            }
        }, 0, UPDATE_INTERVAL);
        return START_STICKY;
    }
}
```

While updateLocationAndCheckGeoFences is succesfully starting the Location Updates removing them is not working.

The Log continuely logging:

> D/GeoFenceService( 9953): Checking GeoFence for Location:♣♣.♣♣♣♣♣♣♣♣♣♣♣♣♣♣/♣♣.♣♣♣♣♣♣♣♣♣♣♣♣♣♣
>
> D/GeoFenceService( 9953):  GeoFence for VoucherRestaurant ♣♣♣♣: GUTSCHEIN jetzt einlösen Distance:315341.0
>
> D/GeoFenceService( 9953): Location Update suspended

I hope someone can help me,

thanks in advance

Comment: You have to remove your listener!

Comment: And how do I do that, I was thinking the removeUpdates is doing this ?

Comment: Have you tried GeoFenceService.mlocListener = null ?

Comment: Yes and the result is Logged as this: Failed to suspend Location Updatenull

Comment: Where does your GeoFenceService come from?

Comment: I added a simplyfied definition of my GeoFenceService class to my post